# Why do I get this error from aws amplify?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

My react application using aws amplify authentication and api gives me the following error in the console when logging in.

```
DataStore - User is unauthorized to query syncFriendships with auth mode API_KEY. No data could be returned.
```

What info do I need to provide, and to who, to figure out how to fix this error message? .

Answer (score 2):

Looks like error is during query from database. You are trying to access via graphQL via `API_KEY` which is expired. You need to generate new api_key and add it in `aws-exports.js` file. Follow this -

1. Go to `GraphQL` from set up panel on Amplify studio.
2. Open your resource from `Deployed graphql resources`.
3. Go to settings on your api from left panel.
4. In `API Details` look for the api key. If it show empty then you need to generate new one.
5. Scroll down and find `Default authorization mode` box.
6. create new api key by new button.
7. copy and paste key value for `aws_appsync_apiKey` in `aws-exports.js` file.
8. Thank me later.

Answer (score 1):

In aws-exports.js try changing
"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AWS_IAM",
to whatever authentication type you are using like. For example,
"aws_appsync_authenticationType": "API_KEY",
https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/authz/q/platform/js/

If this works you can make it permanent by running

> amplify update api

then select graphql and update authorization modes.

Otherwise add additional authorization types in the AppSync schema:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/using-multiple-authorization-types-with-aws-appsync-graphql-apis/

Comment: This worked for me. I did it by going to AppSync -> Settings and adding IAM to "Additional authorization modes" section.

Answer (score 0):

The user (you in your web browser) is not allowed to access the DataStore. You can either grant permissions for guest users or your user has to be signed in.

You can change the Authorization settings in Amplify Studio.

[image]

Comment: I can not find this for the life of me, where in amplify studio?

Comment: I improved the picture. Does it help? You go on aws to amplify, to your project, the backend environment, amplify studio, storage

Comment: Ah I see, I am actually not using the storage feature, this is for uploading files it seems, I am just using data but I will try it